# Is Label (GoTo) calling a Proper Method in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, goto

I have a Big module of code where the coding is done like this..

```
Public sub main ()
.
.
.
proc1:
.
..Some thing
.
.
.
Proc2:
.
..Some thing
.
.
So on till proc15:

.
.
End sub
```

I use to use `GOTO` command to start the execution of the code from one of the "proc" as and when needed.

I want to be able to start the (`Main`) code and start from a any proc's 
without going to the code module..(User will not know where to put GOTO).

Since the whole Routine is heavily related, I cannot use Sub routines to split and call them separately..

(That's why proc labels are used).

---

lets say if I have a combo box in a user form where all the proc's are listed, when the user selects one of the proc and run's the main code..

The Code should run from that proc's

is this possible?

Comment: usage of GOTO in VBA is ALWAYS a bad idea (only exception is in error handling "on error goto"). That it is not possible to work with SUB/FUNCTION is ALWAYS wrong! But as solution: you can pass a parameter to your procedure with the label name. Then insert a Select-Case on top of the procedure and call the goto for each case.

Comment: Yes.. I agree.. But that's a good suggestions Thanks for your update/help..

Comment: @Shyam, every set of procedures can be structured without the GoTo. Could you post some more code to explain better why you cannot make sub-routines?

Comment: @Shyam what do you mean by "without going to the code module"? every module is a "code" module. Please clarify. Also, what does it mean "I want to be able to start the (Main) code"? How do you start the execution of the subroutine? What triggers it?

Comment: @GeneSkuratovsky It sounds like the OP edits the code at run time to control the flow of the program and wants to build a process for others to do this without editing the code.

Answer (score 1):

Given a userform with a ComboBox1 and a CommandButton1:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Select Case ComboBox1.Value
        Case "proc1" 'Or whatever that method is called
            'Do proc1 code here
        Case "proc2"
            'Do proc2 code here
        ...
        Case "procX"
            'Do procX code here
        Case Else
            MsgBox "You did not select a valid Proc"
    End Select
End Sub
```